# como se haria este ejercicio

Tags: linux, permisos

En un ejercicio de administracion de sistemas tengo el siguiente caso :

Los usuarios del departamento de RRHH (y solo ellos) deben poder modificar el archivo “/datos/conta/empleadodelmes.txt”, aunque todos los demás empleados pueden leerlo.  Además, nadie, excepto el administrador del sistema, puede eliminar o crear archivos en el directorio “/datos/conta” , ni siquiera ver su contenido.

Yo,supongo que lo que habria que hacer es,a parte de crear los diferentes directorios y el fichero, establecer estos permisos para el fichero:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root contabilidad    5 ago  6 12:31 empleadosdelmes.txt
```

Pues nos dicen que los de contabilidad(originalmenete RRHH) pueden leer y escribir en el fichero pero el resto solo leerlo.

Para el directorio `/datos/conta` tendria los siguientes permisos:

```
drwxrwx--x 2 root root 4096 ago  6 12:35 conta
```

Pues se nos deja en claro que solo el administrador(root) puede crear/eliminar ficheros/directorios, pero que el resto sigue pudiendo atravesar el directorio, pero no ver su contenido.

Ahora bien, con los permisos ya puestos intento comprobar con mi usuario `k1k4ss0` que esta en el grupo de `contabilidad` que todo funciona. Todo va bien hasta que intento modificar el contenido del fichero `empleadosdelmes.txt` pues me dice que es solo de lectura.

```
┌─[k1k4ss0@parrot]─[~/Desktop/ejemplos_admin/datos/conta]
└──╼ $members contabilidad
k1k4ss0
```

Ademas me di cuenta que al hacer el comando id no aparece el grupo contabilidad listado

```
┌─[✗]─[k1k4ss0@parrot]─[~/Desktop/ejemplos_admin/datos/conta]
└──╼ $id
 uid=1000(k1k4ss0) gid=1000(k1k4ss0)          
 grupos=1000(k1k4ss0),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),119(debian-tor),125(bluetooth),139(scanner),140(pulse),141(pulse-access)
```

Y en el fichero /etc/group tengo lo siguiente:

```
┌─[✗]─[k1k4ss0@parrot]─[~/Desktop/ejemplos_admin/datos/conta]
└──╼ $sudo cat /etc/group | grep "contabilidad"
[sudo] password for k1k4ss0: 
contabilidad:x:1002:k1k4ss0
```

Comment: Ma da alegria entrar en una pregunta con el titulo "de como se haria X en mi ejercicio" y ver que  el usuario de verdad ha trabajado el ejercicio por su cuenta :)

Comment: jaja, yo creo que es lo minimo que se tiene que hacer para poder preguntar XD, osea si lo preguntas y no lo has ni intentado no aprendes nada ;_;

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas reiniciar la máquina para que se actualicen los grupos del usuario.

Un hack provisorio que podés usar para que funcione en el shell actual es: `exec su -l $USER`